# How to make multiple threads that never stop running in a limited pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been trying to find out how can I run in a kind of executor service a few threads that won't leave the `run()` method while there is someone connected to them throught a socket channel.

The executor service could solve my problem if it rotate over the whole pool instead of waiting the method run stops.

Example: I have 200 threads, and I want to run it all in a limited pool of 20 threads.

Any tip?

Answer (score 4):

Any compliant, pooling `ExecutorService` implementation already does this.  It will not reuse a thread until the `run()` method of the callable/runnable has finished running.  When a thread becomes available, that thread will be used to launch the next queued task.

```
List<Runnable> myTasks = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
//...add 200 runnables to myTasks...

ExecutorService threadPoolService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
for ( Runnable task : myTasks ) {
    threadPoolService.submit(task);
}
```

### Edit

If @BalusC's interpretation of your question is correct, it seems like you are looking for something like [*coroutines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutines).  There is no support for that in Java.  I think what you should be looking into is [non-blocking I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/); however you should know that most real-world servers can handle 200 simultaneous threads no problem (since most of them will be blocking at any given time).

Comment: The question is admittedly a bit hard to chiper, but I understood that he want to run 200 tasks **simultaneously** using "only" 20 threads.

Comment: @Balus: So coroutines?  Ok, I didn't get that from my initial read over the question.  The statement "that won't leave the `run()` method..." really confuses things.

Comment: Also, "I have 200 threads" should likely be interpreted as "I have 200 tasks". He doesn't have 200 threads at all, otherwise it was been easy :)

Comment: maybe he wants NIO for 200 socket connections (tasks) across 20 threads.